# Windows vista fails to prompt password for WPA/WPA2 network

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-vista, wpa2-psk

When I try to connect to the network and choose "Connect", the window simple closes and doesn't prompt me for the password to the network.

This only happens when connecting to the network "TDC-0074", not other security enabled networks.

Information about the network:

```
SSID     BSSID             RSSI CHANNEL HT CC SECURITY (auth/unicast/group)
TDC-0074 00:19:70:23:39:28 -73  10      N  FR WPA(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP)
```

I have successfully connected to the network using an iPhone, a Mac and another windows PC.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/vqA9W.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the Wi-Fi network manually in

Control Pane > Network and Sharing Center > Manage Wireless Networks

seems to fix the problem.